What was the reason why they (in Plato's Republic) chose to focus on justice?
I am trying to read Plato's The Republic. It is not easy to understand.
There are two things I just can't understand.
When Socrates and Glaukon come to Kephalos' house the discussion very quickly turns to the question on what justice is.
Plato doesn't explain why they wanted to speak about the virtue of justice.
What was the reason why they chose to focus on justice?
They also started speaking as if justice exists.
Why didn't Socrates ask whether justice even exists at all or not? He questions everything except that ontological assumption?

Little girl I know went to day school as a toddler. She could not bring her stuffed animal to help her sleep during nap time. Now she is ten years old. Thinking about and reporting this "injustice" she wants to go back and punch the day school authorities in the face! Adults do not want to map or relate our sense of justice to early life drama. But this is the origin of our sense of justice and injustice which informs the adult reenactments of drama. Thrasymachus thinks justice is obeying the rulers. During early life adults make rules for children. The sense of justice is implied in politics.

So you're saying that they where angry people who had an injutice done to them?  I guess we need  ore bakground info before reading it. I myself don't think that the question on justice is the first thing on my mind. Plato is confusing. He just begins a book without any explanation whatsoever.

I can have empathy with others, and I can understand their justified anger, even if I am not the one who has experienced an injustice. I am saying that the sense of justice or injustice is inherent in early life drama and continues into adult life. If the sense of justice or injustice is inherent in our social psychology then the discussion of justice as an attribute of politics would emerge without explicit justification. This is distinct from your desire to have the automatic assumption be justified in the context of reading The Republic. Is it injustice to not justify justice in politics?

What's the first thing on your mind? Maybe read about that topic instead?

Unfortunately, it is very difficult to understand (first hand) what is going on, unless you read the prototype, or at least a Greek translation.
Generally, justice (in Plato) is a 2-fold concept: 1. Political justice: The balancing between the three social classes, 2. Ethical justice (personal virtue) : The balancing between the three parts of the human soul (what I want, what I feel and logic).
Until Plato, justice was considered (simplified) to do good to friends and revenge the enemies: to give what you get. This was considered as an act of balancing the cosmic forces.
Socrates, challenges this concept, by refusing to balance an act of injustice with another act of injustice - we should never harm another human being (Crito). A direct proof of which is the acceptance of his death sentence.
Plato, accepts Socrates proposition about justice, by founding "justice" on top of the personal virtue of the integrity of the soul's balance of the acting human being (Politeia) ...
As of the ontological part, for Plato, justice is one of the main virtues of a human being, a concept which was kept intact in classical European philosophy and also in Roman Catholicism.

But why did he refrain from question whether jutice exists or not? Is that really ok in philosophy?

@harry jansson, justice is considered one of the four fundamental human virtues. A virtue cannot be questioned whether it exists or not, it's a disposition towards; you cannot question whether softness exists, you can question whether something can be considered soft or hard.

I think this is because of the title. The title of this book points out the need to explore how to establish the best country, so justice must be the theme.
Imagine a country without justice, or without understanding what justice is, what would happen?
This book actually spent a lot of space discussing topics unrelated to justice, and what impressed me the most was about skills, soul, and the struggle between poetry and philosophy.
They may seem unrelated to the theme, but if we consider the city-state as an individual, it is necessary to discuss skills, soul, and the significance of poetry and philosophy when discussing how to become the best person.
